# When we meet a requirement is better to use "break" or "return" to stop an iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, break

This is the request of the exercise I'm working on:

> The function should sum the elements of the list until the sum is greater than 9000. When this happens, the function should return the sum. If the sum of all of the elements is never greater than 9000, the function should return total sum of all the elements. If the list is empty, the function should return 0.

what is the difference between those two codes:

```
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
  sum_lst = 0
  for number in lst:
    sum_lst += number
    if sum_lst > 9000:
      return sum_lst
  return sum_lst
```

**AND**

```
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
  sum = 0
  for number in lst:
    sum += number
    if (sum > 9000):
      break
  return sum
```

The result will be the same since both of them will stop when the requirement (sum > 9000) will be met.

Comment: In this case, it makes little difference as the method is simple. In practice I use guards and fast returns all the time however, in this trivial case the fast return makes the implementation more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: The only difference between these two cases is stylistic, and that throws this largely into the "opinion-based" category of question. In a more complicated scenario, sure, there might be enough benefit to one or the other to make something resembling a fact-based argument, but here? Nothing.